# autocomplete for IConfiguration maps in vscode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

Using appsettings.json with .net core

You index into the config like this: `var name = Configuration["Position:Name"];`

but `Position:Name` is just a string.

Is there a vscode or C# feature to have autocomplete read the json and complete in the editor?

Comment: Is this a web app? If that's the case you can use sections, IOption<T> and injection to map the configuration to a class.

Comment: this is just app config. creating a class/model or whatever for this would be heavy handed. I want to use appsettings.json in the idiomatic way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Since the configuration is not limited to just a single JSON source but is using 5 different sources by default, it would be somewhat challenging to integrate this into the editor. Possible, sure, but it doesn’t exist as far as I am aware.